# New coder: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

I am writing some code to print high scores from a file. I am new to python and therefore don't have much experience. It'd be great to be told where I am going wrong and how to fix it :)

Please note the code may not be efficient!!!

Searching up the problem and looking to friends for advice, coming from a background with no prior coding knowledge, no one around me knows how to help!

```
file = open("scores.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    filecont = line.split(",")
listOfInt = filecont[::2]
listOfStr = filecont[1::2]
intoDict = zip(listOfStr, listOfInt)
dictOfWords = dict(intoDict)
sortedbyValueDict = sorted(dictOfWords.items(), key = lambda t:t[1]) 
print("\n<<< HIGH SCORES >>>\n")
counter = 0
for i in sortedbyValueDict:
    print(i, ':', sortedbyValueDict[i])
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 5:
        break
```

Scores.txt is as follows:

```
7,jacob,5,rishikesh,3,alex,2,oliver,9,piers
```

I expect the output to be a sorted print of the top 5 high scores in order, however I am getting the error message:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Thank you anyone who helps!

Comment: `for i in sortedbyValueDict:` i is a tuple. you can unpack it as `for key, value in sortedbyValueDict:`

Comment: in your line `print(i, ':', sortedbyValueDict[i])` the `i` is a tuple but it should be an int

Comment: Ah ok. How can I go about easily converting it? As I'm new I've tried int() etc but it's still returning errors.

Comment: When you write `for i in sortedbyValueDict:`, this causes `i` to **already** take on the values that are stored `in sortedByValueDict`. So doing `sortedByValueDict[i]` is not only unnecessary, it's wrong. What you want is just `i`. (But given this understanding, maybe you can think of a better name. Also, if you are coming to Python from another programming language, try to forget as much as possible; if you are a new programmer, then figure out who you were learning Python from before and *ignore that source going forward*, because it will only teach you more wrong things.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import sys

file = open("input.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    filecont = line.split(",")
listOfInt = filecont[::2]
listOfStr = filecont[1::2]
intoDict = zip(listOfStr, listOfInt)
dictOfWords = dict(intoDict)

print(dictOfWords)

sortedbyValueDict = sorted(dictOfWords.items(), key = lambda t:t[1], reverse=True)
print("\n<<< HIGH SCORES >>>\n")
counter = 0
for i in sortedbyValueDict:
    print(counter, ':', i)
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 5:
        break
```

This will give you the result:

```
<<< HIGH SCORES >>>

0 : ('piers', '9')
1 : ('jacob', '7')
2 : ('rishikesh', '5')
3 : ('alex', '3')
4 : ('oliver', '2')
```

You can remove `reverse=True` if you want it in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two different types of iterations.

When you run the following:

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

The output will be:

```
A
B
C
```

If you want to treat i as an integer like in most other languages, you need to use the `range` function:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
0
1
2
```

if you want to iterate over a list in this manner, you need to combine `range` with the `len` function, which returns the length of a list:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i])
```

output:

```
A
B
C
```

In your case, the following will fix your error:

```
for i in sortedbyValueDict:
    print(i)
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 5:
        break
```

or:

```
for i in range(len(sortedbyValueDict)):
    print(i, ':', sortedbyValueDict[i])
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 5:
        break
```